# No exports were found that match the constraint: ContractName Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations

Tags: visual-studio-2013

After open a project on VS13 nothing appearing in the solution explorer, the open project name is appearing on the top title bar.

on run the project getting following error.

No exports were found that match the constraint: ContractName Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations.ITextUndoHistoryRegistry RequiredTypeIdentity Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations.ITextUndoHistoryPleasecorrect before proceeding. (You might rename the current web.config and add a new one).

Last day i was installed tfs 2012 but not configured.

any help?

Answer (score -1):

As stated in [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2015/01/03/fix-visual-studio-error-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint.aspx):

> The fix is to rename or delete the ComponentModelCache in your local folder.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but before putting the issue i have been spend more then 1 hour on the subject to googled and tried almost the solutions suggested, so already the same solution you are saying have been tried and was not worked.